# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface" - Export Deployable Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I'm building an eclipse plug-in. Execution env is JavaSE-1.6

I can deploy the plug-in without any errors, but when the plug-in runs there is an error coming out of it:

> "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>
> "org.eclipse.jface"

Exception stack trace starts with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: swing2swt/layout/BorderLayout
```

Obviously, i have swing2swt.jar in my own plug-in's runtime and classpath, but it seems as though a `org.eclipse.jface` plugin can't find this library.

In a desperate act, i put `swing2swt.layout` package in the "Runtime > Exported Packages" list, imagining this will somehow expose the swing2swt.jar - but this has not resulted success.

Appreciate any help on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to `Bundle-ClassPath` in `MANIFEST.MF`.

And of course to `build.properties` to have it bundled in exported plugin.

Comment: The file swing2swt.jar is already included in both Bundle-ClassPath and MANIFEST.MF